# The countability of "memoir" and "stocktaking" in this sentence

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

I find two nouns in this sentence from [a Time article](http://time.com/4979240/ta-nehisi-coates-we-were-eight-years-in-power/) very strange.

> The Atlantic columns are enriched with **personal memoir**, and **a stocktaking**, as Coates takes the reader through his own life and reflects on how the columns relate to the present.

The noun **memoir**, as far as I know, should be a count noun. This apparently is supported by dictionaries, see [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/memoir) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/memoir). I would have said:

> The Atlantic columns are enriched with **personal memoirs**

Is this a mistake on the part of the Time editor?

On the other hand, I thought **stocktaking** was uncountable (again, so say the dictionaries, [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/stocktaking) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stocktaking)). I thought people normally say "I got some stocktaking to do." or "It's time for stocktaking." However, I did find an example sentence on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stocktaking) that reads:

> It is time for a stocktaking.

Giving it more thought, I can sort of understand why **stocktaking** is used countably sometimes. My guess is it is similar to *reality checks* or *inventory checks*, depending on the usage. But when is it a count noun and when a mass noun? Does it depend upon the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is actually not a mistake, but rather a creative writing technique to metaphorically relate one thing to another thing.  A similar example:

> Her speech was pure **John F. Kennedy** but with an **Obama** flair.

Obviously a "speech" can't be a person, so consider it shorthand for "like Kennedy's speeches".  In a similar way, your example isn't saying that the columns *are* a memoir, but rather they include *memoir-like elements*.

Since this is a kind of *literary* device, I wouldn't recommend using it until you get a good feel for the nuance.  And, as with any creative writing technique, it's best used sparingly, for special emphasis.

You might also see something similar, but with the adjectival "-y" or "-esque" suffixes appended to the noun.

> The speech was **Kennedy-esque**, but with an **Obama-y** flair.

However, these weaken the comparison.  The simile "A *is like* B" is less definite than the (literary) metaphor "A *is* B". (more on [simile vs. metaphor](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-difference-between-a-simile-and-a-a-metaphor))

---

As you might expect, the writer's creative use of "a stocktaking" is also not *incorrect*.  Still, as it plays games with the grammatical structure of the sentence, it's a little disconcerting even for native speakers.  The core sentence is:

> The Atlantic columns are a **stocktaking** (of a certain series of events).

The countable "stocktaking" is a kind of shorthand for "a means to *take stock*", which is to say, "to list or record in detail".  Another example:

> The acrimonious board meeting turned into **a pointless stocktaking** of the current CEO's faults, rather than a discussion of how to fix the company's current problems.

Even though your sources say "stocktaking" is uncountable, I don't see anything wrong with this use.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how _personal memoir_ is adjectival. Isn't it an NP with **memoir** being the head of the NP? Also, it appears I am parsing the sentence differently than the way you parse it. I parse it like this: "The Atlantic columns are enriched with (_personal memoir, and a stocktaking_)" I see _personal memoir_ and _stocktaking_ two substantives connected by the conjunction _and_ in a prepositional phrase led by _with_. Could you elaborate on why you say the core sentence is "The Atlantic columns are a stocktaking"?

Comment: @L.Moneta  Perhaps *adjectival* isn't quite the right term.  It's more like "loose metaphor".  The writer is saying the columns include **elements like a memoir**, and are also **a stocktaking**, as shown by (examples).  It sounds like an odd sentence, and breaks the typical "list" style, but a good author will often do the opposite of what is typical to achieve a certain effect.  In my opinion it's a good sentence, although a little too *dramatic*.

Comment: I see it now. I parsed it wrong. I guess now I understand it should be parsed "The Atlantic columns are [(enriched with personal memoir), and (a stocktaking)]", where _enriched with personal memoir_ and _a stocktaking_ are both predicative.